# using SubTotal in VBA but get over flow error

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get VBA to add up ranges C5:C46, D5:D46 etc. but only show the visible rows to add.

Have tried multiple ways, and have looked at many other codes to try and get it to work but it doesn't

Am after suggestions!

have attached two examples I've used but haven't worked.

```
Private Function AddTotals()

'    Dim rCell As Range
'    For Each rCell In Range("C5:C46")
'        Cells(47, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range(Cells(1, rCell.Column), _
'            Cells(Rows.Count, rCell.Column).End(xlUp)))
'    Next rCell
    Cells(47, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range("C5:C46")) ' Add up all Invoiced Amount
    Cells(47, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D5:D46")) ' Add up all Activities Amount
    Cells(47, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F5:F46")) ' Add up all Cash Payments
    Cells(47, 7).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("G5:G46")) ' Add up all EFT Payments
End Function
```

using the Sum works but using subtotal doesn't.

Comment: You are using a Function. Try making this code a Sub.

Comment: You need to use 9 instead of 109 for the subtotal in order to calculate the hidden rows. See more info [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-subtotal-function).

Comment: tried it as a sub, got the following error

```
Run time Error '28':
Out of stack space
```

Comment: Darxyde, I want to ignore the hidden rows. so I need to use 109. Using 9 would show the hidden rows. Correct?

Comment: What kind of data do you have in "C5:C46"

Comment: @SiddharthRout Range C5:C46 is just money. $60 $180 etc. No particular order for the money either.

All 4 Columns are Money columns.

I did have a subtotal(109, c5:C46) in the actual excel sheet that worked fine, have just tried doing it in VBA as it wasn't always updating (Very heavy sheet) but can't get it to work in VBA

Comment: Nothing wrong with `Cells(47, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range("C5:C46"))` There is some other problem.

Comment: Possible to see your file?

Comment: @SiddharthRout that line that you posted, keeps returning the following,

`
Run-time Error '28':
Out of Stack Space
`

Comment: I thought you said you are getting `Overflow Error`

Comment: @SiddharthRout if you are able to TeamViewer I can let you see the code that way. I have underage kids details in the file and can't share the document for that reason. If you connect via TeamViewer I can show you that way!

Comment: I can but first please confirm is it "Overflow Error" or "Out of Stack Space"?

Comment: Error seems to have changed from trying one method to another. Apologies.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/blob/master/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/out-of-stack-space-error-28.md

Comment: Its out of stack space on

[code]Cells(47, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range("C5:C46"))[/code]

Comment: Are you calling this function from an event code like `worksheet_change`?

Comment: @Rory yeah I am mate.

Now that I think about it, when it updates that cell, it'll then make it re update again correct? Creating an unbreakable loop right?

Comment: Yes - you need `application.enableevents = false` before you make the changes, then reset to `true` afterwards.

Comment: @Rory you're amazing. As soon as you said that, i removed it from the worksheet_change and it worked. Thanks so much, I feel like such an idiot for overlooking something like that!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use explicit references to the worksheet to which your cells/ranges belong. I am running the following code with no issues whatsoever:

```
Sub AddTotals()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The name of your worksheet")
sht.Cells(31, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, sht.Range("C5:C30"))
sht.Cells(31, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("D5:D30"))
sht.Cells(31, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("F5:F30"))
sht.Cells(31, 7).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("G5:G30"))

End Sub
```

Here's my results on some random data:

[image]

Comment: Cheers mate!

Turns out I had it in the worksheet_change and basically creating an unbreakable loop as it kept updating the worksheet and kept triggering itself. I removed it from the worksheet_change and it works amazing now!

Too many long hours behind the screen i think! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change if needed

        .Cells(31, 3).Formula = "=Subtotal(109,C5:C30)"
        .Range(.Cells(31, 4), .Cells(31, 7)).Formula = "=Sum(D5:D30)"

    End With

End Sub
```